# For what purpose one would want to create a class's instance inside the same class's main?

Tags: java, initialization

I came across this kind of example and had difficulty to understand it's actuall purpose:

```
class YieldDemo extends Thread
{
   static boolean finished = false;
   static int sum = 0;
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      new YieldDemo ().start ();
      for (int i = 1; i <= 50000; i++)
      {
           sum++;
           if (args.length == 0)
              Thread.yield ();
      }
      finished = true;
   }
   public void run ()
   {
      while (!finished)
         System.out.println ("sum = " + sum);
   }
}
```

I've never seen this kind of implementation - why initiating a the new class **inside** the same class object and not **outside** the class? is there any particular reason?

Comment: Don't think that there is any specific reason, just less code for a example.

Comment: I have so many problems with that code... (actually, just 3 main ones: unsynchronized access to mutable shared variables; extending `Thread` rather than implementing `Runnable`; a really busy loop).

Comment: @AndyTurner - it's not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact you are `outside` of the class object itself. The `main method` is a static method, thus it has no dependency on any object instance.

You could also move the `main method` to any other `java file`. In general it will also work. However, you need to put `static` methods in some file. As every `java file` needs to be a class, you may put the method in the class it works for. For example, the class `Math` in java is a pure utility class, it has no `non-static` method.

However, if you create something like this:

```
public final class Value {
    private final int mValue;

    public Value(int value) {
        mValue = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public Value increase() {
        return new Value(mValue + 1);
    }
}
```

It can actually make sense if you want `Value` to be immutable (not change its internal value). So, calling `increase()` does not increase the value itself but creates a new instance of this object, with an increased value.